# IIS 7.5 - redirection from one domain to another, while maintaining paths

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a website that opens from different domains (site.domain.eu and site.domain.ru). I need to create a rule that redirects all traffic from site.domain.ru to site.domain.eu, preserving the paths, i.e. Links like site.domain.ru/page1?=test should also be redirected to site.domain.eu/page1?=test. Can you please tell me the solution to this puzzle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this, maybe...

```
<rule name="redirect .ru to .eu" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site.domain\.ru" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://site.domain.eu/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```